# Lucene Customize TokenStream

Tags: java, text, lucene, analysis

I am using Lucene to count words (see example bellow).

My question is **how can I set my own filters in Lucene?** For example to add my custom StopFilter, ShingleFilter, etc.

I suppose that some token stream filter(s) is already being used since Hello, hello and HELLO are converted to "hello".

```
public class CountWordsExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(
            Version.LUCENE_47, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47)));
    Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new TextField("foo", "Hello hello how are you", Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("foo", "hello how are you", Store.YES));
    document.add(new TextField("foo", "HELLO", Store.YES));
    writer.addDocument(document);
    writer.commit();
    writer.close(true);

    //  ShingleFilter shingle = new ShingleFilter(input);

    IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);

    Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(indexReader);
    Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(indexReader);
    for (String field : fields) {
        TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, field)
                .iterator(null);
        BytesRef bytesRef;
        while ((bytesRef = termEnum.next()) != null) {
            if (termEnum.seekExact(bytesRef)) {

                DocsEnum docsEnum = termEnum.docs(liveDocs, null);

                if (docsEnum != null) {
                    int doc;
                    while ((doc = docsEnum.nextDoc()) != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
                        System.out
                                .println(bytesRef.utf8ToString()
                                        + " in doc " + doc + ": "
                                        + docsEnum.freq());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (String field : fields) {
        TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, field)
                .iterator(null);
        BytesRef bytesRef;
        while ((bytesRef = termEnum.next()) != null) {
            int freq = indexReader.docFreq(new Term(field, bytesRef));

            System.out.println(bytesRef.utf8ToString() + " in " + freq
                    + " documents");

        }
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
hello in doc 0: 4
how in doc 0: 2
you in doc 0: 2
hello in 1 documents
how in 1 documents
you in 1 documents
```

Answer (score -1):

So the answer was quite straight forward. The way how to define my own token processing is to define my own analyzer. For example:

```
import java.io.Reader;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class NGramAnalyzer extends Analyzer {


    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName,
            Reader reader) {
        TokenStream f = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader);
        f = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, f); 

        Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, reader);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like old code to me.  Won't work in 4.0 onward (which you are clearly using).  You'll need to override `createComponents` instead, see the [`Analyzer` documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) for an example.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Now it should meet 4.7 requirements.

Comment: Okay, and why are you using two different tokenizers?  I haven't seen that done before.  Usually, you would want to save the the tokenizer used in your filter chain (in this case, the `StandardTokenizer` and pass it into your `TokenStreamComponents`.  Is there something that is meant to accomplish?

Comment: No, it had no any particular reason - just to demonstrate how to customize the code. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: No, what I mean is, you want to pass the same tokenizer used in the filter chain, not just one of the same type.  like: `Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer...; TokenStream f = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, source); return new TokenStreamComponents(source, f)`.  The one passed to your filter and the one returned in the components should be the *same object*.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how much it matters in this case, if you pass in a tokenizer set up exactly the same.  I don't really know all about how Lucene uses `TokenStreamComponents.source` internally.  It may make no difference, for all I know, but it certainly could make a difference (it's passed around a lot, including to things like the `ReuseStrategy`, so there may be places where it assumes they are the same object and relies on state being consistent), and there's no sense in going to the trouble of constructing a new one anyway.